# Getting out of memory error while starting a Activity in android App?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am working on an app where one activity is a very complex code with **different views inflated in a single layout like webview**(which is using html files from sdcard with images),imageviews,scrolls.At starting this Activity I am getting these errors.

```
        E/AndroidRuntime(600): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  ... 29 more
        E/AndroidRuntime(600): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2722)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:379)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:174)
        E/AndroidRuntime(600):  ... 32 more
```

How to solve this problem I have tried this code but still not knowing what to do?

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.rootView));
    System.gc();
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }
```

What is the possible way to solve this problem? Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You get the OutOfMemoryException if the image pixels exceeds the limit.(the maximum resolution is 2048*2048)

You can reduce the Image's pixels by using Bitmapfactory.Options -

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri.getPath(),options);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(),myBitmap);
updateDrawable(d);
```

While using your images in the activity reduce their resolution.

Note - inSampleSize=2 means it reduces the size by 1/2 and the resolution by 1/4.

Try to keep the value of inSampleSize in power of 2 too get best results.

Hope, it works out for you. Any query, please comment.

Comment: How to use this when there is variable number of images used each time activity runs?

Comment: when you set the image use this to change the properties of each image. Or you can even use this while saving the files to your application file system.

Answer (score 1):

After searching and seeing the above answer I have written a simple snippet by just modifying code from Android User.I have used this which is successfully working.This code setCallback the view's background and even recycle all the present bitmap used.

```
     @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.rootView));
        System.gc();
        }

 static void unbindDrawables(View view) {
     try{
     System.out.println("UNBINDING"+view);
            if (view.getBackground() != null) {

                ((BitmapDrawable)view.getBackground()).getBitmap().recycle();


                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
                view=null;
            }

            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

EDIT:

A new thing I discovered today using images less than 20 kb of size is good for memory-optimization and less u have to go through out-of-memory error.

Comment: where do you call start new activity and finish() this one?