# Android activity fails to launch from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a strange problem where the activity does not launch and the phone freezes. From the logcat I get when debugging from Android Studio and the following lines keep repeated.

```
11-04 16:04:49.956 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-04 16:04:49.971 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-04 16:04:49.976 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-04 16:04:49.981 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-04 16:04:49.981 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-04 16:04:49.996 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.rayat.pricewiz time:2648880
11-04 16:04:50.016 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-04 16:04:50.016 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
11-04 16:04:50.051 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-04 16:04:50.071 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.rayat.pricewiz time:2648959
11-04 16:04:50.091 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-04 16:04:50.091 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
```

It is a simple activity with no complicated work.

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.rayat.pricewiz.view.activity.tabshopping.ShoppingSessionCreationActivity">
    <TextView style="@style/WizardPageTitle"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:text="@string/select_list" />
    <com.rayat.pricewiz.view.widget.AnimatedRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:id="@+id/llList"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
            android:divider="#F0F0F0"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:id="@+id/lsvList"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
    </com.rayat.pricewiz.view.widget.AnimatedRelativeLayout>
    <com.rayat.pricewiz.view.widget.AnimatedRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:id="@+id/rlListDetail"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/light_header_grey"
            android:id="@+id/hdrLists"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:id="@+id/btnGoBack"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_light_grey"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_header_text"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/txtListName"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnGoBack"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnOverflowMenu"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnOverflowMenu"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView
            android:id="@+id/listDetailView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hdrLists"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
            android:divider="#F0F0F0"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/llLoading"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loader2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:text="@string/loading"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.rayat.pricewiz.view.widget.AnimatedRelativeLayout>
    <com.rayat.pricewiz.view.widget.AnimatedRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_bar"
        android:id="@+id/layout_lstAvailableStores"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
            android:divider="#F0F0F0"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:id="@+id/lstAvailableStores"/>
    </com.rayat.pricewiz.view.widget.AnimatedRelativeLayout>
    <com.rayat.pricewiz.view.widget.AnimatedLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_bar"
        android:id="@+id/layout_lstSelectStore"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.35">
            <!--<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />-->
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/white">
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="#F0F0F0"
                android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_onclick_highlight"
                android:id="@+id/lstSelectedStores">
            </ListView>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.rayat.pricewiz.view.widget.AnimatedLinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_bar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtGoBack"
            style="@style/btnOrangeWhiteBackground"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:text="@string/go_back"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSelect"
            style="@style/btnFlatOrange"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtGoBack"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtCancel"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/select_list_for_shopping"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            style="@style/btnOrangeWhiteBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txtCancel"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Code:

```
public class ShoppingSessionCreationActivity extends BaseActivity implements RequestCompletionListener {

    private int state;
    private final int STATE_INITIAL_SCREEN = 1;
    private final int STATE_STORES_TOTAL_BILL_SCREEN= 2;
    private final int STATE_MERCHANT_STORES_SCREEN = 3;
    private final int STATE_SESSION_STARTED_SCREEN = 4;
    private final int ERROR_TYPE_LIST_NOT_SELECTED = 1;
    private final int ERROR_TYPE_LIST_EMPTY = 2;
    private Animation fadeIn, fadeOut;
    private PleaseWaitDialog dialog;
    private User user;
    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private TextView txtTitle, txtGoBack, txtCancel, txtListname;
    private AverageBillStoreAdapter averageBillStoreAdapter;
    private SelectedStoresAdapter selectedStoresAdapter;
    private ListSelectionAdapter listNamesAdapter;
    private ListView lstAvailableStores, lstSelectedStores,lstLists;
    private AnimatedRelativeLayout rlListDetail, rlAvailableStores, rlLists;
    private AnimatedLinearLayout llSelectedStores;
    private Button btnSelect, btnGoBack;
    private String selectedListRID;
    private ListAdapter mListAdapter;
    private ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView mListDetailView;
    private boolean mapLoaded;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        inflateLayout(R.layout.activity_shopping_session_creation);
        setupActionBar(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_shopping_session_creation), true);
        checkActiveSession();
        setupUI(savedInstanceState);
        loadListNames();
    }

    public void setupUI(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Location location = getCurrentLocation();
        user = getLoggedUser();
        fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
        dialog = new PleaseWaitDialog(this,getResources().getString(R.string.getting_local_stores_header),
                getResources().getString(R.string.getting_local_stores_detail));
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        selectedListRID = "";
        txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        rlLists = (AnimatedRelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.llList);
        rlLists.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
        rlLists.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);
        rlListDetail = (AnimatedRelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlListDetail);
        rlListDetail.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
        rlListDetail.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);
        rlAvailableStores = (AnimatedRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_lstAvailableStores);
        rlAvailableStores.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
        rlAvailableStores.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);
        llSelectedStores = (AnimatedLinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_lstSelectStore);
        llSelectedStores.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
        llSelectedStores.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);
        lstLists = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lsvList);
        listNamesAdapter = new ListSelectionAdapter(this);
        lstLists.setAdapter(listNamesAdapter);
        mListAdapter = new ListAdapter(this);
        mListDetailView  = (ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView)findViewById(R.id.listDetailView);
        mListDetailView.setOnHeaderClickListener(new StickyListHeadersListView.OnHeaderClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHeaderClick(StickyListHeadersListView l, View header, int itemPosition, long headerId, boolean currentlySticky) {
                ImageView arrow = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imgArrow);
                if (mListDetailView.isHeaderCollapsed(headerId)) {
                    mListDetailView.expand(headerId);
                    arrow.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down));
                } else {
                    mListDetailView.collapse(headerId);
                    if (Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language().equals("eng")) {
                        arrow.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right));
                    } else {
                        arrow.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        mListDetailView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
        btnGoBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGoBack);
        btnGoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadListNames();
            }
        });
        txtListname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtListName);
        btnSelect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                com.rayat.pricewiz.entity.List item =  listNamesAdapter.getSelectedListRID();
                if (item != null) {
                    selectedListRID = item.getListRID();
                    ListItemDataSource listItemDataSource = new ListItemDataSource();
                    List<ListItem> listItems = listItemDataSource.getListItemsByListRID(selectedListRID);
                    if (listItems.size() > 0) loadStores(selectedListRID);
                    else showListSelectionError(ERROR_TYPE_LIST_EMPTY);
                } else {
                    showListSelectionError(ERROR_TYPE_LIST_NOT_SELECTED);
                }
            }
        });
        lstAvailableStores = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstAvailableStores);
        lstAvailableStores.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                rlAvailableStores.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                llSelectedStores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Store2 store2 = (Store2) averageBillStoreAdapter.getItem(i);
                getMerchantStores(Integer.toString(store2.getMerchantRefKey()));
                state = STATE_MERCHANT_STORES_SCREEN;
            }
        });
        averageBillStoreAdapter = new AverageBillStoreAdapter(this,location);
        lstAvailableStores.setAdapter(averageBillStoreAdapter);
        selectedStoresAdapter = new SelectedStoresAdapter(this,location);
        lstSelectedStores = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstSelectedStores);
        lstSelectedStores.setAdapter(selectedStoresAdapter);
        lstSelectedStores.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                final int position = i;
                IDialogButtonClickListener listener = new IDialogButtonClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void buttonOkClick(Object obj) {
                        createSession((Store2) selectedStoresAdapter.getItem(position), selectedListRID);
                    }
                };
                ConfirmDialog confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialog(ShoppingSessionCreationActivity.this, listener, getResources().getString(R.string.confirm_store_selection_header),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.confirm_store_selection_details));
                confirmDialog.show();
            }
        });
        txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtGoBack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtGoBack);
        txtCancel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCancel);
        txtGoBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (state == STATE_MERCHANT_STORES_SCREEN) {
                    loadStores(selectedListRID);
                } else if (state == STATE_STORES_TOTAL_BILL_SCREEN) {
                    loadListNames();
                }
            }
        });
        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        /*map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                mapLoaded = true;
            }
        });*/
    }

    public void loadListNames(){
        state = STATE_INITIAL_SCREEN;
        ListDataSource dataSource = new ListDataSource();
        java.util.List<com.rayat.pricewiz.entity.List> lists = dataSource.getLists();
        listNamesAdapter.updateData(lists);
        listNamesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        changeView(state);
    }
}
```

And here is how I am launching from main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShoppingSessionCreationActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

after a while, I get OOM error:

```
11-04 16:11:10.036 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
11-04 16:11:10.036 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/CrashlyticsCore: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
11-04 16:11:10.036 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/CrashlyticsCore:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
11-04 16:11:10.036 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/CrashlyticsCore:     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:44)
11-04 16:11:10.036 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/CrashlyticsCore:     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:275)
11-04 16:11:10.036 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/CrashlyticsCore:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
11-04 16:11:10.036 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/CrashlyticsCore:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.rayat.pricewiz, PID: 7417
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 186636 byte allocation with 177056 free bytes and 172KB until OOM
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:747)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:568)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3747)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1818)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.rayat.pricewiz.request.WebImageLoader.displayImage(WebImageLoader.java:31)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.rayat.pricewiz.view.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:127)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.rayat.pricewiz.view.activity.tabshopping.ShoppingSessionCreationActivity.onCreate(ShoppingSessionCreationActivity.java:103)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
11-04 16:11:10.136 7417-7417/com.rayat.pricewiz E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Any advice what is going wrong?

**Edit:**
[Android Manifest](http://pastebin.ca/3234549)

**Edit 2:**
When I debug, I found it that it keeps on calling `onCreate` method again and again

Thanks,
Noorul

Comment: Mm may be check these out (related to bitmap and out of memory): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536521/outofmemoryerror-when-loading-activities
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620848/getting-out-of-memory-error-while-starting-a-activity-in-android-app

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: please post AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: How can I add more data as the post is limited to 30000 chars?

Comment: added link to android manifest

Comment: Your app consumes a lot of memory. Try to remove layout (and code) in order to find the memory-consumed code. try to add largeHeap into application-manifest tag. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: When I debug, I found it that it keeps on calling `onCreate` method again and again

Comment: @Noorul, try to remove the code/layout tags in order to check. Or use memory analizator (I know for Eclipse, but not for Studio).

Comment: @trololo Sorry, I did not get, do you want me to remove formatting in the question?

Comment: @Noorul, No. I just say: namely remove code in your app step by step to find when the app not crash. What happens if you launch empty Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @trololo, I figured that two activities were launching each other due to corrupt data in sqlite database.